# vba excel AutoFit cells height is not working

Tags: vba, height

I want that the height of the text in a current cell to be automatically adjusted. HEIGHT not width.

I tried this code and it is not working so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    With Worksheets("Lohnbeurteilung").Cells
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        .WrapText = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the merged cells on the sheet?

Comment: Did you try to make `.WrapText = True` before `.EntireRow.AutoFit`?

Comment: Privet Aleksey
I just tried to put .WrapText before,
still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (tested):

```
With Worksheets("Lohnbeurteilung").UsedRange.EntireRow
    .WrapText = True
    .AutoFit
End With
```

Note. If you need to autofit only the selected range, you can use `With Target.EntireRow` in `Worksheet_SelectionChange`